# Android, How to use the camera

Tags: android, camera, android-emulator

I would like to do something like this.

If the user presses "Pictures" than i can choose either to pick a picture from "Picture folder" or take a new picture,

How can I do this and how can I use the cam? 
I have problems useing the cam, Does the cam work in the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the camera on the simulator, it's working well :)

Don't forget to give you the security rights into the Manifest.

Don't forget also than every android devices doesn't have one !

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html